# HTTP Get Request for ICan (.ics) file

Tags: angular, api, http, angular6, icalendar

I'm trying to get a shared calendar from Airbnb into an Angular 6 App. I simply cant get it to work! If I call the URL from 'postman' I have no issues and the values come back. If I enter the URL in web browser it downloads the file. Just cant get Angular 6 to get the file.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
// import {RequestOptions, Request, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from 
'@angular/common/http';

@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
template: 'look at the console <br /> Resposne: {{data}}'
})
export class AppComponent  {
data: any
constructor(
  private http: HttpClient
){

// let requestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers:null, withCredentials: 
// true }); 


 let getHeaders: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'text'
});



this.http.get('https://www.airbnb.co.uk/calendar/ical/XXXXX.ics?s=XYZ', { headers: getHeaders})
  .subscribe(data =>
  this.data = data
   )
  }
}


@NgModule({
 imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule ],
 declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
 export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: You probably have CORS issue here. What doesn the console report?

Comment: Probably right as it reports CORS issue in debugger cant understand why if it works in URL and Postman .........Error: Access to fetch at 'https://www.airbnb.co.uk/calendar/ical/XXXXXX.ics?s=XYZ' from origin 'https://angular-rh7r9f.stackblitz.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: There is no ‘Cross Domain’ issue when you request it directly:-)

Comment: The only way to resolve this is to use a (server-side) proxy..

Comment: I tried this at local level where the angular app gets downloaded into the browser with the same issue. When you say server side proxy...are you suggesting that the change has to be at the AirBNB side?

Error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.airbnb.co.uk/calendar/ical/XXXX.ics?s=XYZZ' from origin 'http://airbnbclient.hmosoftware.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Browser -> airbnb = not allowed due to CORS so solution is Browser -> proxy -> airbnb whereby the proxy is on the same domain as your angular app (or on a different one, but then you have to set CORS headers yourself).

Comment: So this proxy should be on your side..